# Loop object animation with pause between each repeat

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

Using PowerPoint 2013. If I set an Animation to Repeat = Until End of Slide, it does just that, but the animation repeats happen back to back. If I add Delay = 10 seconds, the first animation waits 10 seconds before triggering, but then repeats back to back as before.

Any way to make a 10 second pause between *each* repeat?

Google didn't find any useful answers, and I assume the answer is "no," but never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes". But instead of repeating an animation, you have to repeat the slide itself. Create a custom show and add your looping slide to it from Slide Show -> Custom Slide Show. Don't forget to check the "Loop Continuously unlit Esc" in Slide Show -> Set up Slide Show. After that, set that slide to advance automatically under Transition menu. After that, hide your slide by right clicking it and select Hide. This concludes the looping effects.
To make it joined with other slide, create a new slide with action button in it which hyperlinks to the custom slide show you made.
View your slide show to see a miracle happens :)

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible to do (and better if you have other animations you don't want to repeat) by triggering your animation from an audio file.

You can either loop an audio file and have the animation trigger each time the audio starts again or you can create a longer audio file and have the animation trigger at increments along the playtime of the audio file. I'll only describe the first method but you should be able to figure out the second if that suits your purposes better.

Creating your recording

1. Navigate to Recording, Audio, Record Sound
2. The length of the recording will correspond to the gap between each repeat of the animation.
3. Click on the audio file, Playback, Add Bookmark

Looping your recording

4. Navigate to Animations, Animation Pane
5. Right click on your audio file in the Animation Pane and select Timing
6. Set Repeat to 'Until End of Slide' or however long you'd like your animation to repeat for

Triggering your animation

7. Right click your animation from the Animation Pane (the animation you want to be repeated)
8. Select Timing
9. Click the Triggers drop down
10. For 'Start effect on play of' choose your bookmark

And you're done. Your audio file will now loop and each time the bookmark you created is reached your animation will fire. You can adjust delays and add more bookmarks as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue today and was astounded at how convoluted the process is. My solution is a hack - make an object that slowly fades over, say, 20 seconds, but place it off the screen. This way, the presentation will appear to pause as a shape is slowly fading in but cannot be seen because it's off screen. If you want to have a longer delay then daisy chain a series of shapes to fade in one after another off screen.